# how to define the stash embedded template?

Tags: stash, embeds

I would like to use the Stash embed functions, but I don't know how to define the template path.

In the Stash docs:

```
{!-- Stash template file at /path/to/stash_templates/test.html --}
{stash:embed name="test"}
```

How to define and set the path to the embedded template called test??

It is similar to the variable setting?

```
{!-- set a variable --}
{exp:stash:set name="foo"}bar{/exp:stash:set}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the docs explain, you need to setup your paths in your config:

```
$assign_to_config['stash_file_basepath'] = '/path/to/stash_templates/';
```

The docs are here: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki/Installing-%26-upgrading